# How to deal with British pound sign in knitr

Tags: r, latex, knitr

I have R code that contains a pound sign £ used for the British currency. I produce a LaTeX file with knitr and the £ sign is not displayed. Usually I would use \pounds to typeset the £ sign in LaTeX, but obviously I can not use that in the R code. Could knitr be made to automatically convert £ to \pounds in the .tex file it creates?

Here is a minimal example:

```
\documentclass{article}
\begin{document}

<<p>>=
"£"
@

\end{document}
```

In the .tex file this produces

```
\begin{knitrout}
\definecolor{shadecolor}{rgb}{0.969, 0.969, 0.969}\color{fgcolor}\begin{kframe}
\begin{alltt}
\hlstr{"£"}
\end{alltt}
\begin{verbatim}
## [1] "£"
\end{verbatim}
\end{kframe}
\end{knitrout}
```

which pdflatex then can not handle correctly until by hand I change all the £ to \pounds.

Comment: Please try to add `\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}` to your preamble.

Comment: @user2706569 I tried that. It makes no difference.

Comment: Which encoding did you use to save the file?

Comment: @user2706569 I am using utf8 (the default in RStudio).

Comment: Hm … though I'm not sure how this should help, you could try to also add `\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{lmodern}`. If this neither works, we're stuck. Changing all £ to `\pounds` should be possible via [output hooks](http://yihui.name/knitr/hooks/#output_hooks) but it wouln't solve the apparent encoding/font issues in the document.

Comment: @user2706569 That actually leads to some weird-looking output, where in place of the £ it has Âč. Encoding issues are a mystery to me. I have in the past avoided having to worry about encoding issues by only using standard LaTeX symbols.